# UWP App Sending Email with EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync Wont add Attachment in New Outlook Email

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, email-attachments, xamarin.uwp

Using following Microsoft article, I am trying to launch default email application from a UWP app running on my Windows 10 desktop.  If the app is Mail app, it will be opened and attachment is added to new mail.

However, if the default email app is Outlook (in my case Outlook 2016 but other versions are possible, too), then attachment is not added and Outlook crashes shortly after new email dialog.  No attachment gets added either.

This is the link with the example I am using:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email

Here is my code

```
private async Task CreateEmail(string messageBody, string archiveFilePath)
{
    StorageFile attachmentFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(archiveFilePath);
    var subject = string.Format("Sending file {0}", attachmentFile.DisplayName);

    var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    emailMessage.Body = messageBody;

    if (attachmentFile != null)
    {
        var stream = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(attachmentFile);
        var attachment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailAttachment(attachmentFile.Name, stream);
        emailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    var emailRecepient = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient("me@home.com");
    emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecepient);

  // call this on main thread; otherwise, no New Email box open
  await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
  {
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
  });
}
```

and here is how I call it

```
private void SendArchiveFile()
{
    myLogger.SendArchive(path =>
    {
        CreateEmail("test", path); 
    });
}
```

- Running this code with Mail app set as default app will work fine.
- However, running it with Outlook set as default app will crash
  outlook, New Email will open shortly, no attachment is added, then
  Outlook crashes.

I have found few posts stating that you cannot call any Win32 apps including Outlook from UWP app without violating store policies.

But that is huge limitations since many businesses cannot change their mailing system just because UWP is not compatible.  Also, the system should offer apps that are compatible like Mail app or other compatible apps installed rather than just picking default email app including the ones that are not working with UWP such as Outlook.

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
var subject = string.Format("Sending file {1}", attachmentFile.DisplayName);
```

Should be:

```
var subject = string.Format("Sending file {0}", attachmentFile.DisplayName);
```

The index is zero based and you pass only one argument. This should raise an error in the debugger, and if you step through the function you'll see it exit with the following exception before the EmailMessage is created and sent.

> System.FormatException occurred   HResult=0x80131537   Message=Index
>   (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the
>   size of the argument list.

Once you fix that your code should successfully launch the default mail app. As noted in other threads you've posted on, the attachment will only go through with the in-box UWP mail app. Outlook 2016 is not plumbed to handle the EmailManager's EmailAttachment

Comment: Thanks Rob, I actually found the problem but no solution yet.  You are right, I had that issue with index but that was not the reason of the issue.  The reason is that the code is called from background thread.  I update the question above to reflect my new explanation and what the real problem is.  The problem is that I cannot add attachment to new email created in Outlook.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi Rob, what if Outlook is not there in the system/or not configured? what will ShowComposeNewEmailAsync give me in return?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers (rather, a sadness) from Microsoft, mostly at MSDN forums, attachments are simply ignored when attaching to Win32 mail app like Outlook.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5a539ff6-ce81-4f05-83a0-8bf430d827f8/uwpwindows-10-c-universal-windows-app-email-with-attachment?forum=wpdevelop

I'd say, this may make sense on a smartphone device, but definitely not on laptop/PC.